# Print a word diagonally?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to python, so I'm trying to understand how to print a word diagonally (either right to left or vice versa).

So far, I've been trying to write it all under one function by defining the function.

Then using a `for` loop and inside including `if` statements as to whether right to left = `True` or `False`, but it's not working as I'm unaware of how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

For top left to bottom right:

```
>>> word = 'HelloWorld'
>>> for i in range(len(word)):
...     print ' '*i, word[i]
...
 H
  e
   l
    l
     o
      W
       o
        r
         l
          d
```

For top right to bottom left:

```
>>> word_length = len(word)
>>> for i in range(len(word)):
...     print ' '*(word_length-i), word[i]
...
           H
          e
         l
        l
       o
      W
     o
    r
   l
  d
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
from __future__ import print_function

word = 'JustATest'

for i in range(len(word)):
    for j in range(len(word)):
        if i == j:
            print(word[i], end="")
        else:
            print(' ', end="")
    print()
```

#### Output

```
J        
 u       
  s      
   t     
    A    
     T   
      e  
       s 
        t
```

#### Remarks

- The first import is used to imitate python3's print-function when using python2

  - this print allows to use `end=""` to print without creating a newline at the end
- Beeing on a diagonal means, that `i==j`
- Finishing iterating over one dimension (in this case: the inner one) needs to create a new line

Answer (score 1):

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) works really well for this case.

```
>>> for index, char in enumerate('HelloWorld!'):
>>>     print(' ' * index + char)
H
 e
  l
   l
    o
     W
      o
       r
        l
         d
          !
```