# How can I print letters down below

Tags: python, string, letter

I don't know how can I program this.

[image: needthis]

I tried to do it but I know only opposite direction.

[image]

This is what I program [image: porgram]

Comment: You should post your code, not a screenshot of your code

Comment: Describe to yourself how you would do this on paper.  Think about spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a word diagonally? (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39938483/6045800)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own backwards counter with `range`. `zip` that with the original string and you have your count.

```
>>> text = "ahoj"
>>> for i, c in zip(range(len(text),0,-1), text):
...     print(" "*i + c)
... 
    a
   h
  o
 j
```

Or, use enumerate to get indexes and do a little subtraction

```
>>> for i,c in enumerate(text):
...     print(" "*(len(text)-i) + c)
... 
    a
   h
  o
 j
```

Answer (score 0):

I've two solutions for this, maybe this is more readable?

```py
slovo = input("Zadaj slovo: ")
max_spaces = len(slovo) - 1
for i, char in enumerate(slovo):
    print(" " * (max_spaces - i) + char)
spaces = len(slovo) - 1
for char in slovo:
    print(" " * spaces + char)
    spaces -= 1
```

Output:

```
Zadaj slovo: ahoj
   a
  h
 o
j
   a
  h
 o
j
```